# Cannot Launch Amazon AWS CLI from Command Line on Mac

Tags: amazon-web-services

I followed all the instructions provided by Amazon for installing AWS CLI found here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-install-macos.html

My machine is running the Zsh Shell. So in step three I edited .zshrc instead of .bash_profile.

The error message I am receiving is

```
zsh: command not found: aws
```

Here is how the .zshrc file looks now.

```
export PATH="$HOME/.bin:$PATH"

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH

eval "$(hub alias -s)"

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

I believe that the export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH might be redundant given the line above it that was already in place.

Comment: Are you using default python which shipped with macOS? You should install python via homebrew and install awscli again.

Comment: @taskiner Yes, I am using 2.7.10. According to the specs listed on https://aws.amazon.com/cli/ the minimum required version is "2.6.5 or higher." Regardless, I am going to try updating Python and see what happens.

Comment: OK, so after doing some research, I read that using Homebrew to update Python is not ideal. So I went with the installer from the Python website. When I open terminal to check to see which version I'm running, it still says the same version. Seems the two instances are living side-by-side. Not sure how much I want to muck around with Python considering the version I have accessible from terminal meets Amazon's requirements.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

OK, so I got it working...

First I switched from zsh to bash shell via the terminal command:

```
exec bash
```

Then I ran:

```
pip --version
```

Just to confirm that pip and Python where both in fact installed and working.

From here I ran:

```
brew install awscli
```

This was the critical missing ingredient that I did not have on my first run through.

At the end of the install process Amazon prints to screen a list of "Caveats" for completing installation.

According to the Caveats I took the following two steps...

First, added the following to ~/.bashrc to enable bash completion:

```
complete -C aws_completer aws
```

Then added the following to ~/.zshrc to enable zsh completion:

```
source /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_aws
```

Now I am able to run the command "aws" via either shell.

Comment: I get this error in zsh on mac -> 9:46:28 Fri 25 code 1015:15-126$ ll /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_aws
ls: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_aws: No such file or directory
9:47:06 Fri 25 code 1016:16-1$

Answer (score 0):

I followed instructions at:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-implement-federated-api-and-cli-access-using-saml-2-0-and-ad-fs/.

I can confirm that I do have oh-my-zsh on my mac, and I performed the following installs :

```
pip install boto
pip install requests
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

prior to creating the requested `credentials` file under `~/.aws` folder.

Also, my credentials file had:

```
[default]
output = json
region = us-west-2
aws_access_key_id =
aws_secret_access_key =
aws_session_token =
```